# listview addFooterView problems

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout, android-listview

i have content i need to display above my listview and below, so much that a scrollview would be great to use if you could use scrollviews and listviews together.  Since thats not the best solution, i've been trying to do a couple of things to add footer content to my listview,

here the pic below shows what happens when i add a different type of row as the last row.  I  can't get my content to fill the width of the row

[image]

I have a couple of buttons that need to go in the footer.  I'm using a custom adapter that extends BaseAdapter.

I have also tried using the addFooterView but i'm confused on how to use the addFooterView method if you are implementing your own adapter.  Anyone have any simple examples of how to implement addFooterView on a custom adapter

or

is there a way i can get the row at this position (as seen in the picture ) to display better, here is the code i'm using to create this footer row

```
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_listview_footer, null);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ll);
        return ll;  // return ll as convertView in getView function
```

edit:

here is the xml for my footer layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/red" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/ll">
    <Button android:id="@+id/specialInsButton" style="@style/button" android:text="Add Special Instructions" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/addToBagButton" style="@style/button" android:text="Add To Bag"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/quantity" style="@style/standard" android:text="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

here is the xml for style/button

```
<style name="button">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">17px</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>

    </style>
```

standard style

```
 <style name="standard">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Fixed from API19

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use addFooterView with a custom adapter. Just be sure to make the addFooterView call before the call to listview.setAdapter().

```
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_listview_footer, null);
listView.addFooterView(v);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: that works fine but my footer view is still not showing properly, any ideas why its still only a few pixels wide instead of "fill_parent" wide ? ? ?

Comment: I don't see anything that might be causing this.  These buttons are supposed to be stacked vertically and take up the whole width of the screen, right?  You should use 'sp' instead of 'px' in your textSize property, but that should be unrelated.  Could you post @style/standard for the editText?

Comment: you're right, here's the style <style name="standard">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    </style>

Comment: Nothing seems wrong to me.  Have you tried looking at the view using hierarchyViewer?  It should help in finding which view is causing the error. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html

Comment: This turned out to be a necessity for me for footers to appear at all on 4.1.1. They worked fine on 4.4.4 with the same code...

Comment: @adamdport Yep, just had the same problem. It's noted in the developer site now: "Note: When first introduced, this method could only be called before setting the adapter with setAdapter(ListAdapter). Starting with KITKAT, this method may be called at any time. If the ListView's adapter does not extend HeaderViewListAdapter, it will be wrapped with a supporting instance of WrapperListAdapter."

Comment: Fixed from API19